# Do I apply expectation correctly?

Tags: probability, expected-value

I stumbled upon the following problem recently:

A terrible crime has been committed.

The main attraction, a rare and precious diamond,
was stolen just before the museum opened its doors.
Patrons were horrified and the detectives were called immediately.

Here are their main suspects: (16 photos)

Alice needs to find the criminal by asking as few "yes"/"no" questions as possible.
How to achieve this might not be clear, but what about the opposite?

Suppose that Alice's strategy is to go through the suspects one by one, asking

"Was it Audrey?"
"Was it Bill?"
etc.
How many such questions would she have to ask, on average, to identify the criminal?

Is it correct to say?

$$
E(X) = S * P(X=x),$$ Let X represent the number of questions we have to ask,
$$E(X = i) = 1/16\\
E(X) = 1/16 * ( 1 + 2 + ... + 16)\\
E(X) = 1/16 * (16 * 17/2) = 8.5
$$

Solution from the author which I don't understand:

> With this strategy for her questions,
> Alice is committed to going through the suspects one by one,
> asking Bob whether or not they're the criminal.

> They could get lucky and identify the criminal on the first question,
> or they could get unlucky and not do it until the last.
> Since each suspect is equally likely,
> we'd expect them to ask about 88 questions on average.

> If they get through the first 15 suspects without finding the criminal,
> then they know it's the person they haven't asked about.
> For that reason, the average number of questions they'll need is 7.5,
> slightly less than half the number of suspects.

Comment: What the author is pointing out is that if you have cleared $15$ suspects of the crime, you needn't ask a question to the now certain criminal, and so the expected value will get reduced accordingly. Btw, the assumption of each suspect having an equal probability of being the criminal, and that questioning will definitely reveal the criminal, is itself **very suspect**

Comment: I found the formatting of your question to be a barrier to reading, so I made modifications, I hope without changing your meaning. // Still puzzled by `1515` and `7.5,7.5` in the last paragraph. Can you check those?

Comment: @BruceET Thank you very much for your modifications. You are correct, there is no need to duplicate 7.5 in the last paragraph

Comment: @trueblueanil Thank you very much for your reply. For some reason, I thought that this reduction of the solution space (removal of 16th criminal) should be built-in in the expectation formula. Now I understand that this was a very stupid assumption and the reduction is domain-specific.

Comment: Glad to be of help !

Answer (score 1):

@trueblueanil is correct.
I will have the author's answer if I remove the 16th criminal prior to my calculations.